# Converging an if statement within parenthesis

Tags: python, performance

I am looking for a way to simple converge some code to make life simpler

```
foo = []
if bar != None:
    foo.append(bar)
```

Is there a simple way to make that look like this:

```
foo = []
foo.append(bar) if bar != None
```

I understand that there isn't a need for such a thing but I want to start to make my code more readable and reliable

Thanks

Comment: I agree, the first version is more readable and people are generally more used to it.

the best thing you can do to make the second example work is to do `foo.append(bar) if bar is not None else None`, which adds more to the unreadability.

Comment: There are various tricks you can use if you're doing code golf, eg `bar and foo.append(bar)`, but for normal code, the most readable (and Pythonic) way is `if bar is not None:` `foo.append(bar)`. OTOH, if you are appending multiple items in a loop, then you could use a list comprehension instead of `.append`, or perhaps a generator expression with `filter`, although many (including Guido) don't like `filter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last block of code is not more reliable or readable than the first block. However if you want an alternative you might think about this

```
foo = []
foo += [element for element in [bar] if element is not None]
```

At least you have your one liner. But if it is only for one element then the first example you gave is good enough.

Comment: I believe I need to thank you for adding alternative to my vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

You could write `a.append(bar) if bar != None else None`. But don't do that, that's completely unreadable. As others have said, your original three-liner is a way to go and standard way of doing what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo.extend([bar] if bar is not None else [])
```

But don't do that, that's completely unreadable.